# Change redirect of "email must be verified" path in Laravel 7?

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I implemented the must verify email system in Laravel 7. If a user hits a route that should be for verified visitors, the user is currently being redirected to view `auth.verify`. How to change this and to redirect it to route `user.profile`?

Comment: maybe you should check the middleware and see what it is doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a middleware `EnsureEmailIsVerified` to overwrite  `auth.verify`

then apply this middleware to all your route

```php
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;

class EnsureEmailIsVerified
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $redirectToRoute
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $redirectToRoute = null)
    {
        if (! $request->user() ||
            ($request->user() instanceof MustVerifyEmail &&
            ! $request->user()->hasVerifiedEmail())) {
            return $request->expectsJson()
                    ? abort(403, 'Your email address is not verified.')
                    : Redirect::route('user.profile');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

and here redirect based on your requirement